# WCM - How to display content item elements from a Menu Component pointing elsewhere?

Tags: tags, components, wcm, ibm-wcm

In IBM's Web Content Manager I have a page in the path:

```
TopArea > MainContent > SiteArea > content
```

which uses a Menu Component to pull items from a slightly different path, such as

```
TopArea > OtherContent > OtherSiteArea > othercontent
```

So, in the Menu Component, when I use `[Property]`, `[Placeholder]`, or `[Element]` tags, it pulls the data from `othercontent`. However, I need to use some kind of tag to pull data from the page that the menu component is being displayed on `content`.

Anyone know how to do this?

---

Here is a more specific example:

- `othercontent` has Name: `3ee5fc`.
- `content` has Name: `Home Page`.

When using `[Property context="autofill" type="content" field="name"]` it displays `3ee5fc`.

What kind of tag could I use (or what could I do) so that it would display `Home Page` instead?

Please note that there are multiple content items that are using this menu component, so I can't hard code (select) the content item, I need a tag that will find it based on what item is calling the menu component.

Comment: How are you including the Menu component in your "Home Page".  If it's in a text field in a presentation template, can you display that page's "name" in that presentation template before you include the menu component?

Comment: No, it's not in a presentation template. One content item has a component reference that calls the menu component. I guess I didn't word this very well, but basically I was trying to figure out how to get info from the content item that had the component reference to the menu component.

Comment: So basically, the PT just says [Element key="compRef"] and that calls the Menu component which I wanted to display info from  both the content item that carries the menu comp along with all the info coming from the site area the menu was pointing to.

Comment: Are you still having problems? Have you tried this? https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+reference+an+Element+from+a+different+Site+or+Site+Area

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the context attribute.  "autofill" will display from the items the menu has selected, where "current" will display the field from the item the menu is placed in.

Comment: context="autofill" was already being used in the question. The issue is that basically one content item has a component reference that calls the menu component, which displays content from another site area... and I couldn't figure out how to pull info from the content item with the component reference while ALSO pulling info from the content that the menu component was already pointing to.